# Démission de mon poste de modérateur

Tags: discussion, moderation

Je démissionne de mon poste de modérateur volontaire et vous êtes en droit de savoir pourquoi. Je ne peux pas accepter ce que la société Stack Exchange vient de faire (en privé, mais je pense que cela va rapidement s'ébruiter).

La vie en société conduit forcément à la confrontation de points de vue. C'est d'autant plus le cas qu'un lieu d'échanges est international, une rencontre de personnes de cultures différentes. Lorsqu'on interagit avec d'autres, il y a des bornes à ne pas franchir — par exemple, le racisme n'est pas acceptable, point final — et à l'intérieur de ces bornes, il faut s'ouvrir à la diversité. Des fois cela implique d'écouter des points de vues multiples, des fois cela implique de mettre les désaccords en sourdine, et des fois cela implique de faire des compromis.

J'ai été témoin d'un désaccord entre des modérateurs. Il y avait des arguments valables des deux côtés. Une des parties était consciente que ses actes pouvaient faire du mal même s'il n'y avait aucune volonté de nuire, et a fait des efforts pour éviter de blesser. L'autre partie a exigé que tout soit fait suivant leur volonté, sans se préoccuper du mal qu'elle causait. Dans la dispute qui s'est ensuivie, il y avait clairement une victime et des agresseurs. [Vous pouvez lire le point de vue de la victime (en anglais)](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5193/stack-overflow-inc-sinat-chinam-and-the-goat-for-azazel) et [un point sur la situation qui n'a fait qu'empirer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336526/stack-overflow-is-doing-me-ongoing-harm-its-time-to-fix-it).

Stack Exchange est intervenu en rajoutant de l'huile sur le feu, en soutenant fermement la partie qui refusait tout débat, et a mis la victime à la porte. Je ne peux pas me sentir en sécurité dans une telle atmosphère, et il est hors de question que je participe à la créer.

Je participe sur Stack Exchange depuis neuf ans et j'y ai été modérateur volontaire pendant plus de huit. Quitter ce poste représente un gros changement. Je suis profondément déçu de partir comme cela, mais je ne peux pas continuer ainsi.

Je reste attaché à la construction d'une bibliothèque partagée de connaissances. Je pense qu'un site de questions-réponses est un complément utile à une encyclopédie, rôle que remplit Wikipédia. En revanche, la manière dont Stack Exchange est gérée maintenant m'amène à douter qu'elle puisse remplir son rôle, surtout auprès de cultures autres qu'une certaine frange de la société Étatsunienne. Je vais réfléchir au bien-fondé ma participation sur ce réseau.

Comment: For those who want [to read this in English](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1650/11432).

Comment: Sorry to see this, Gilles. I know in various cases I've been an annoyance over the years, but I have always vastly appreciated the effort you've put in to helping myself and others learn French, even as you wished the site were more like English.SE and less like ELL.SE. I think many, many thousands of people have had personal interactions with you across SE that left them for the better.

Comment: Voir peut-être ces Q&A ([1](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5193), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333763), [3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331513)) pour un certain éclairage/contexte...

Comment: Thank you for standing up for something important.

Comment: [This post on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333965/176183) keeps up to date with all the ensuing moderators resignations. Gilles was just the first.

Answer (score 15):

Merci pour tout ce que tu as apporté à ce site.

---

**7-10-19**
*Stack Overflow* a mis du temps à reconnaître ses torts. Mais grâce à Gilles et tous ceux qui se sont élevés contre la façon indigne dont a été traité un de ses modérateurs [nous avons maintenant l'espoir](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334551/176183) que SE puisse survivre et que nous puissions continuer à échanger sur les sujets qui nous intéressent et nous font réfléchir.

@Gilles, si l'issue du conflit se règle de façon correcte et digne pour tous, on peut espérer que tu reviennes sur ta décision. Certes être modérateur sur 3 sites doit être beaucoup de travail puisque tu l'étais aussi sur [CS](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1650/11432) et [emacs](https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/555).

---

**19/11/2019**
Tu cites wikipedia, alors :
[Why does Fram's ban on Wikipedia seem so similar to recent events here?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/338655/176183http:)

Comment: Le dernier lien fonctionne pas. Je suis curieux

Comment: Merci, @Laure. C'est intéressant.

Answer (score 10):

J'admire l'intégrité, l'empathie et la solidarité et je crois qu'écouter la voix de sa conscience mène assurément à bon port. Merci pour tes bons et  loyaux services de modérateur, ce n'est pas de tout repos ! J'ai dû lire un petit moment pour comprendre un peu le contexte ([1](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5193), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333763), [3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331513) etc.) dans lequel s'inscrit ton geste sans savoir très exactement ce dont il est question.

En plus de l'idée de « construction d'une bibliothèque partagée de connaissances » dont tu parles, j'aimerais rappeler, si tu permets, que l'idée de contribution sous licence *CC* et autres et les valeurs qui la sous-tendent sont complètement indépendantes de tout véhicule qui en facilite la production. J'en suis personnellement reconnaissant aux professionnels auteurs, entre autres, de bien vouloir :

> [...] encourager la réutilisation de leurs œuvres, en les offrant pour
>   utilisation sous termes normalisés et généreux par des personnes qui
>   cherchent l’utilisation créative de ces œuvres et ceux qui veulent
>   bénéficier de cette symbiose. ([creativecommons.org](https://creativecommons.org/faq/fr/#quest-ce-que-cc-et-que-faites-vous))

Idée qui est facilitée par le réseau. J'espère qu'on aura le plaisir de lire de tes nouvelles et riches contributions ici et/ou ailleurs, qu'importe la fréquence, parce qu'à chaque fois ça compte. On peut s'en convaincre en sachant, par exemple, qu'une contribution comme [celle-ci](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/145197) a été utilisée dans le cadre d'une recherche sur la violence en milieu de travail ; ça peut sembler banal mais ça a fait une différence dans l'analyse des données. On se souvient que ça a marché et ce fut bien instructif pour la personne qui posait la question et combien d'autres lecteurs par la suite à mon avis, donc merci encore !

Il serait vraiment dommage de se priver de toutes ces solutions qui baignent librement et font continuellement des vagues dans cette mer de savoir, et que des contributeurs de ton étoffe et solidaires de cette personne dont tu parles veulent partager ainsi que de leur rayonnement à titre de modérateurs, tout comme il serait malheureux il me semble de ne pas leur permettre par le fait-même d'encourager davantage la réutilisation de toutes ces œuvres par la communauté et tout le monde finalement. Peut-être que des gestes d'apaisement, qui précéderaient un éventuel rapprochement entre les groupes d'intervenants dans le cadre de projets rassembleurs où tous pourraient collaborer et où serait rendu à chacun ce qui lui revient, demeurent possibles et seraient indiqués ici.

Dans tous les cas merci bien et salut, Gilles !