# jlliagre, congratulations for reaching 100k!

Tags: discussion

<sub><sup>*Inspired by the tradition I saw on [The Workplace](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=congratulations)*</sup></sub>

Hello and happy New Year everyone!

For the first time in French SE's history, [a user has reached a total of 100k reputation](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/1109/jlliagre). It's really something special, particularly on a smaller SE website such as this one. So, **congratulations to jlliagre for this awesome milestone!**

This progression, impressively steady throughout the years (9 of them in total!), shows an amazing dedication and passion for our beautiful language. jlliagre, your answers are consistently precise and clear. Even better, you always do your best to be friendly to everyone, which can be difficult in a Q&A website that is not a forum. You are a very good example to follow, and I, as a younger user, always looked up to you and will continue to do so.

In the name of, I'm sure, almost everyone here, thank you for your contribution!

To 9 more years!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thank you!

I never thought I would ever reach that 100k level here, especially as French isn't really my domain of expertise, but well, time made that possible.

I'm more a IT guy so started contributing on the Stack Exchange network eleven years ago on Server Fault, Super User, StackOverflow then Unix&Linux. One of my goals, beyond of course helping people asking questions for which I could provide an answer, was just to practice written English. I specially found very convenient to have people correcting my replies.

A couple of years later, I discovered FSE and started answering questions here too. I learned a lot by doing so. I definitely moved from a slightly too prescriptive approach (*Dire et ne pas dire*, *Académie française*'s style) toward a much more descriptive and pragmatic approach to the French language. I started to pay much more attention to typography rules and also realized there was many recurring mistakes I made when writing French without even noticing.

Meanwhile, it was funny to see my kids thinking I was playing some sort of online game they weren't able to understand the rules. I gained some respect from them when I explained to them there was "players" all over the world and they saw my rank going higher and higher on the scoreboard ;-)

Being there was less of a fun when I received aggressive comments and it was sometimes difficult to refrain feeding the trolls. Hopefully, they weren't too many and generally disappeared or slow down after a while, possibly/likely after moderators' actions. It was however sad to see some cool users leaving FSE because they were fed up with this kind of harassment.

Another sad time occurred after a few missteps culminating with Monica Cellio firing and the obnoxious behavior SO staff exhibited during the months that followed. Historic mods [Gilles](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/d%C3%A9mission-de-mon-poste-de-mod%C3%A9rateur) and [Stéphane Gimenez](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/759/une-autre-d%C3%A9mission) stepped down after that. I hesitated to completely leave but concluded that wouldn't have any impact at all, and on the contrary would have left the field open to someone some of whose answers ridiculed FSE.

To a certain extent, thwarting some of these terrible answers boosted my reputation, so I guess I have to thank him for that ;-)

Anyway, Happy New Year to all, *Paci é Saluta à tutti !*

Comment: Vous êtes corse? Ou vous souhaitez juste la bonne année en corse?

Comment: @spaghettibaguetti Il y a du vrai dans ce que tu dis ! ;-)

Comment: @spaghettibaguetti mais ça ne m'empêche pas de le faire aussi en [provençal](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56606548#56606548) !

Comment: I'm so happy for you, Jlliagre! I quickly recgonised your name as you have more than once answered my questions and questions of others. Mind you, I'm so shocked to learn that French isn't your field of expertise! I'm also very sorry for any difficulties that you've faced here.